Scrapy crawl a website and lose some items
Here is my main spider class below
import scrapy
from xxx.items import WorkItem

class XXXSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "xxx"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://example.com/xx/xx"]

    def parse(self, response):
        year_list = response.xpath('//ul[@class="p-accordion"]/li')
        for year in year_list[:2]:
            release_dates_url_of_year = year.xpath('.//div[@class="genre -s"]/a/@href').extract()
            for date_url in release_dates_url_of_year:
                yield scrapy.Request (
                    url = date_url,
                    callback =self.date_detail_parse
                )

    def date_detail_parse(self, response):
        work_list = response.xpath('.//div[@class="swiper-slide c-low--6"]/div')
        for work in work_list:
            actress_name = work.xpath('.//a[@class="name c-main-font-hover"]/text()').extract_first()
            if actress_name is not None:
                item = WorkItem()
                item['actress_name'] = actress_name
                item['image_hover'] = work.xpath('.//img[@class="c-main-bg lazyload"]/@data-src').extract_first()
                work_detail_url = work.xpath('.//a[@class="img hover"]/@href').extract_first()

                if work_detail_url is not None:
                    yield scrapy.Request (
                        url = work_detail_url,
                        callback = self.work_detail_pares,
                        meta = {'workItem' : item}
                    )

    def work_detail_pares(self, response):
        item = response.meta['workItem']
        pics_list = response.xpath('.//div[@class="swiper-wrapper"]/div')
        pre_images = []  
        for pic in pics_list:
            img_url = pic.xpath('./img/@data-src').extract_first()
            pre_images.append(img_url)
        item['pre_images'] = pre_images
        item['name'] = response.xpath('.//div[@class="p-workPage l-wrap"]/h2/text()').extract_first().strip()
        item['id'] = response.xpath('.//span[@class="c-tag02 c-main-bg-hover c-main-bg"]/../text()').extract_first()
        item['company'] = 'xxx'
        item['release_date'] = response.xpath('.//div[@class="p-workPage__table"]/div[2]//div[@class="item"]/a/text()').extract_first()
        actress_detail_url = response.xpath('.//div[@class="p-workPage__table"]/div[1]//div[@class="item"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url = actress_detail_url,
            callback = self.actress_detail_pase,
            meta = {'workItem' : item}
        )

    def actress_detail_pase(self, response):
        item = response.meta['workItem']
        item['actress_avatar'] = response.xpath('.//div[@class="swiper-slide"]/img/@data-src').extract_first()
        item['like'] = False
        item['mark'] = False
        yield item




I used year_list[:2] here to quickly scrape data, testing only the first two years. However, when comparing the results with the website, I found that a lot of item data was missing, and only a small amount was scraped, which is strange. What could be the reason?
I also tried passing the item using deepcopy, but there was no difference.
p.s: When I scrape just one of the elements in year_list, specifically one of the release_dates_url_of_year, it successfully scrapes all the data.In other words, the problem may lies within the for loop.

You shouldn't share the same item object between different callbacks.
